# Laravel Route::resource naming

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following in my routes.php

```
Route::resource('g', 'GameController');
```

I link to these generated routes via `HTML::linkRoute('g.index', 'Title', $slug)` which produces a link to `http://domain/g/demo-slug`

What I am looking to do is verify if it is possible to have the prefix be declared in one place so I'm not hunting for links if a URL structure were to change.

For example, I would want to change `http://domain/g/demo-slug` to `http://domain/video-games/demo-slug`

I was hoping to use the similar functionality with the standard routes, but that does not seem to be available to resource routes.

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getUpdated'));
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know it's true you can't have named routes for a resource controllers (sitation needed) but you can contain them in a common space using [`Route::group()`](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-groups) with a prefix. You can even supply a namespace, meaning you can swap out an entire api with another quickly.

```
Route::group(array(
    'prefix' => 'video-games', 
    'before' => 'auth|otherFilters', 
    'namespace' => '' // Namespace of all classes used in closure
), function() {
    Route::resource('g', 'GameController');
});
```

**Update**

It looks like resource controllers are given names internally, which would make sense as they are referred to internally by names not urls. (`php artisan routes` and you'll see the names given to resource routes).

This would explain why you can't name or as it turns out is actually the case, rename resource routes.

I guess you're probably not looking for this but `Route:group` is your best bet to keep collections of resources together with a common shared prefix, however your urls will need to remain hard coded.

Comment: Wouldn't prefixing my routes still presents the problem above? 'domain.g.index' would be hardcoded instead of 'g.index'. Is there a better way to create a link based on a resource route?

Comment: Added section on to the answer

Answer (score 1):

Route::group() takes a 'prefix'. If you put the Route::resource() inside, that should work.

Tangent, I find this reads better:

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@getUpdated', 'as' => 'home'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give custom names to resource routes using the following syntax

```
Resource::route('g', 'GameController', ['names' => [
  'index' => 'games.index',
  'create' => 'games.create',
  ...
]])
```

This means you can use `{!! route('games.index') !!}` in your views even if you decided to change the URL pattern to something else.

[Documented here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) under `Named resource routes`